# How to store a boolean value in a MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know this question appeared before, but in my case I couldn't find out what's going wrong.

I use MongoClient from mongodb library.

Here is my code:

```
databaseInstance.collection('items').updateOne({
        _id: new mongodb.ObjectID(itemId)
    }, {
        $set: {"isVisible": true}
    })
```

It saves `isVisible` field as 'true':

```
{ _id: 57f50b0cfe8c5e25fcacad23,
  item: 'myitem',
  isVisible: 'true' }
```

Comment: From where you get the json output?

Comment: Your `updateOne` call is correct, so there's something else going on here. Can you create a MCVE?

Comment: Is this the document that you see in the node.js app or this is what you see actually in the database? It is a bit strange that the id is like that: `_id: 57f50b0cfe8c5e25fcacad23,`. What is the mongo version that you are using and what is the nodejs mongodb driver version that you are using?

Comment: The issue was with the format of the incoming data. true was passed as a string, not a boolean. When I fixed it, it solved the issue. thanks!